# How to create custom events (they have to be at netbeans palette)

Tags: java, swing, events, jpanel, jbutton

I've been looking for hours a solution for my problem, I'm kinda new programming in Java languaje and already managed to create a custom panel that contains 6 custom buttons, but now I need to create an event that can detect wich one I pressed, I've done this with C# but can't find a way in Java.

This code is in C# but of course I need something similar for Java.

```
/// <summary>
/// Enumerator with buttons states
/// </summary>
public enum EstadoBoton
{
    Aceptar = 1,
    Nuevo = 2,
    Editar = 3,
    Cancelar = 4,
    Eliminar = 5,
    Imprimir = 6,
    Salir = 7
}
/// <summary>
/// Delegate method for buttons events
/// </summary>
/// <param name="edoBoton"></param>
public delegate void BotonPresionado(EstadoBoton edoBoton);

public partial class ctrlBotones : UserControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// here I keep the state of the button
    /// </summary>
    private EstadoBoton estadoBoton;
    /// <summary>
    /// Event that manages the state of the button
    /// </summary>
    public event BotonPresionado BotonPresionado
    {
        add { this.botonpresion += value; }
        remove { this.botonpresion -= value; }
    }
    private BotonPresionado botonpresion;
    public ctrlBotones()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

That example shows at visual studio's list of events the name "BotonPresionado" so I can select that event and the code will be generated.

I would apreciatte a lot any help you could give me.

Thanks in advance and sorry if my english is not very good, still learning. :)

I forgort to write the generated code when I press the custom event at GUI.

```
//As we can see, it generates en event for this control not for the buttons.
private void ctrlBotones1_BotonPresionado(HerramientasInterfaz.EstadoBoton edoBoton)
    {
        //I just use a switch to check wich button I pressed.
        switch (edoBoton)
        {
            case HerramientasInterfaz.EstadoBoton.Aceptar:
                Aceptar();
                break;
            case HerramientasInterfaz.EstadoBoton.Nuevo:
                Nuevo();
                break;
            case HerramientasInterfaz.EstadoBoton.Salir:
                Close();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would simply add an ActionListener to each JButton, perhaps an anonymous inner class. Look up the ActionListener and JButton tutorial for more on how to do this: [ActionListener Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), [JButton Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Comment: *"new programming in JAVA.."*  For future reference, it is Java, not JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

ok, Aaron Daw i under stud some extent that you want to create your own "event".That means to reuse the same code for the components.

I tried custom components(JButtons,JMenu) in past this way

```
public class MyMenu extends JMenu
{
public MyMenu(ImageIcon i,String s)
{
    super();
    setIcon(i);
    setText(s);
    setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
}
}
```

Create object for "MyMenu",here we don't need to add properties each time, that was advantage.

In a same way i tried with custom listener for JButton it's working.when you click on button it will prints "button pressed"
this is customEvent class

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;


public class CustomListener 
{
JButton button;
public CustomListener(JButton b)
{
button=b;

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==button)
        {
            System.out.println("button pressed");

        }
    }
});

}
}
```

this is main class

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class MainClass extends JFrame
{
JButton jbutton;
public MainClass()
{
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(jbutton());
    setSize(800,600);
    setVisible(true);
}
public JButton jbutton()
{
    if(jbutton==null)
    {
        jbutton=new JButton("click");
        new CustomListener(jbutton);
    }
    return jbutton;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    new MainClass();
}
}
```

now I can REUSE the actionListener.

Comment: Thanks padman for your answer, but I think is not exactly what I need, I added more code of what is generated for the event, also I really need that the event could be selected at netbeans GUI, think that I can totally do at C# using the first part of the code I posted.

Answer (score -1):

my friend

if you are looking for an **userinterface** similar to that of *visual studio* like easy **drag drop**

then in **netbeans** right click on your project then click **new JFrame Form** (if its not there then in others) and you will have a easy **drag drop** userinterface

then drop a `JButton` from **palette** and then double click that `JButton` and there you get **event** for that `JButton` ....